# Multiple programs share a source file when autotools generating makefiles

Tags: c, makefile, autotools

This question concerns mostly Unix/Linux style C development. I am using `autotools` to generate `Makefile`.

There are two programs share a source file named `utils.c`.

The structure of my source tree goes like this:

```
app/
    src/
        server/
            server.c
            ...
        client/
            client.c
            ...
    include/
```

The question is where should I put the shared source file and how should I write my `Makefile.am` or `configure.ac` to make it work.

The current `configure.ac` only specify the `AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile src/Makefile])`

And the current `src/Makefile.am` goes like this:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = server client
server_SOURCES = server/server.c
client_SOURCES = client/client.c
server_LDADD = $(DONT_KNOW_WHAT_TO_WRITE)
client_LDADD = $(DONT_KNOW_WHAT_TO_WRITE)
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do the relevant bits of your `Makefile.am` and `configure.ac` files look like currently?

Answer (score 0):

If it is just one relatively small source file, you might as well add it to the respective _SOURCES lines.

If the shared code consists of multiple files, you could create a static library.
https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/A-Library.html